# Formatting a string in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to retrieve and format the `time` via XML

```
<match time="8:20 PM" contestID="96775" formatted_date="16.09.2021" status="Not Started">
```

I am able to to get the string as `8:20 PM` which I would like to string the PM or AM in the sting.

If I use the following:

```
myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

It strips the `:` which I still require.

Can anyone help me with the reg. expression I need for my issue?

### UPDATE

Wanted result should be 8:20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use xpath to get the `@time` attribute. from that, you can split the time string by space :)

example: use xpath lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath

```js
var xpath = require('xpath')
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser

var xml = '<match time="8:20 PM" contestID="96775" formatted_date="16.09.2021" status="Not Started">';
var doc = new dom().parseFromString(xml);
var timeStr = xpath.select("string(/match/@time)", doc);
var [time, period] = timeStr.split(' ')
console.log(time, period)
```

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Updated with sample code. not tested yet :)